# How to click a GoogleMap Polygon below a Marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

My android application uses a `GoogleMap` with `Polygons` to show areas of interest to the user. If the user clicks on a `Polygon` the click event is handled by the `OnPolygonClickListener` and an info dialog is displayed. My problem lies with a `Marker` showing the current location of the user which is blocking click events passing to the `Polygon` below.

[image]

**Sidenote: The click area of the marker also seems to be larger than visible. This circle actually blocks nearly the whole square below it.**

What I tried so far:

- Catching the click event and ignore it

  ```
  getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
      public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
          return true;
      }
  });
  ```

Does not work in this case because we can either return false which triggers the default behavior (zooming in on the marker) or true which ignores the click event altogether since - [per documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#click-index) - there is only one event per click.

- Changing the z-index of the polygon: Does not work because - again per documentation - "Markers are effectively considered to be in a separate z-index group compared to other overlays or shapes, regardless of the z-index of the other overlays" so click events are always passed to potential markers first.

So is there a way to make a `Polygon` below a `Marker` clickable or at least reduce the clickable marker area to the visible size?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823783

Comment: Well thats unfortunate. So reducing the clickable marker area is already out of the question..

Comment: When Marker is clicked, check whether its location falls within the boundaries of one of your Polygons and if it does, trigger the Polygon click event.

Comment: I guess that validates as a fast fix (assuming we use PolyUtils). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of MrUpsidown and using googlemaps [PolyUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html) I implemented a manual validation to trigger a `Polygon` targeted click manually. I can not tell about efficiency of `containsLocation()` when handling a larger amount of polygons but it works for the time being.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
            if (marker == userLocation) {
                mPolygons.forEach { polygon ->
                    if(PolyUtil.containsLocation(userLocation?.position, polygon.points, false)) {
                        // Do Polygon stuff here
                        return@forEach
                    }
                }
                true
            } else {
                // Do optional marker stuff here
               true
            }
    }
```